# Swift - set clear background color in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am having a problem with my `UITableView`. Eventually I want it to look like this (the white rectangle).

[image]

How can I set `.backgroundcolor` so it is clear, like in the picture?? 
Another problem I am having is that my `TableView` is "pre-filled" with empty `cells`..

I've tried this but somehow it is not working:

**`TableViewController` class**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath)
    let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentWish.wishName
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell
}
```

**Custom `Cell` class**

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(checkButton)
    self.backgroundColor = .clear

}
```

**How I create my `UITableView`**

```
let theTableView: WhishlistTableViewController = {
   let v = WhishlistTableViewController()
    v.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    v.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    v.view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    v.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

My `UITableView` is working fine with all its functions. It's just the `backgroundcolor` and the empty `cells`...

I am grateful for any help :) I couldn't find anything on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WhishlistTableViewController` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set background to clear
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

    // add clear view as tableFooterView
    // to prevent empty cells
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.tableFooterView = v

    // ... rest of table setup
    tableView.register(WishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "WishCell")
}
```

Now you no longer need `v.view.backgroundColor = .clear` in your declaration.

Another option if, for example, you sometimes want to use an instance of `WhishlistTableViewController` *without* the transparent background, change your declaration from:

```
let theTableView: WhishlistTableViewController = { ... }
```

to:

```
lazy var theTableView: WhishlistTableViewController = { ... }
```

Comment: `lazy var` is working perfectly for me thanks :) Do you also know how I can disable autofill with emtpy `cells`?  I hope you know what i mean :D

Comment: Did you see the comment in my example code to add a clear `tableFooterView` to prevent empty rows? Is that what you mean?

Comment: sorry I actually missed that :D and it worked perfectly again.. Thanks! Really appreciate the help